# How to convert a file size (string) to a double in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using 2 custom functions to get estimated file transfer time of a file.  Function #1 gets the file size of file then passes that file size to Function #2, which gets the total file transfer time by dividing the file size by the transfer speed.

Problem is -- Function #1 returns a [String]: ie. 12 GB, 232.13 MB. 15 KB, etc...

Function #2 expects a [Double] as the parameter data type.

This gives me a value conversion error:

> Cannot convert value "4.13GB" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input
>   string was not in a correct format."

Confusing part is that if I call the Function #2 directly from the command line -- I can type in 4.13GB and it will execute the calculation.  You can even do simple math from a Powershell command:  ie. 4.13GB/3 and it will return results.

Here is a sample of my script:

```
$filesize = Get-FileSize ('myfile.txt') # This outputs "4.13GB"
$transfertime = Get-Transfertime -Size $filesize -Speed 5.5mb -Overhead 10
```

File Size in Powershell seems to be a DOUBLE.  How can I convert my $filesize variable to a DOUBLE so that Function #2 accepts the value?

Comment: Hi, `([double]4.13GB + 0).GetType().Name` returns `double`.

Comment: Make 4.13GB a STRING and you'll get the error:  ([double]"4.13GB" + 0).GetType().Name

Comment: Invoke-Expression: `(iex "4.13GB").gettype()`

Comment: This worked, @wOxxOm!  Let me know if you want to update with an official answer and I can reward you the points.  Thanks!

Comment: Be careful -- calling `Invoke-Expression` on whatever a function happens to return is fairly dangerous if the function ever returns something you don't want to *execute*. This also fails if the function presents a number in a locale-specific format ("4,13 GB"). Even the inclusion of a space breaks it! A far better solution is to rewrite `Get-FileSize` so it simply returns the size in bytes -- if that needs to be presented in human-readable form, you can just do `(Get-FileSize ...) / 1GB` (or write a `Format-Size` function to separate these concerns).

Comment: `"4.13GB" - 0`. But why your `Get-FileSize` return string in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

`'2.5kb'` is different from `2.5kb` same way `'2*3'` is different from `2*3`. 
You can read about numeric multipliers in [PowerShell Language Specification.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389)

If you want the multipliers to be evaluated before casting the string to double, you pass it as scriptblock to second function:
`$sc = [scriptblock]::Create('2.5kb')`.
The advantage of this approach is that the string is being parsed, so you can be sure that second function can ivoke it: 
`[double]($sc.Invoke()[0])`. 
If you tried convert incorrect string to scriptblock, you'll get an error: 
`[scriptblock]::Create('2.5 kb')`.